# Set a maximum to the instantiation operator of a class - Python

Tags: python, class, attributes

I want my code to return a error, if the user enters a to high instantiation operator.
Like this:

```
class test:

    def __init__(self, value):
        if value > 300:
            return ERROR
        else:
            self.value = value
```

But i don't just want to print out an error, i want the console to give an error out.

Comment: How about `assert value <= 300`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
def __init__(self, value):
    assert value <= 300
    self.value = value
```